# Find Center of Circle given Radius, Circumference Point, and that Point's Rotation

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles

I need to find the center point of a circle $(x,y)$ given:

• The radius $\mathbf r$ of the circle

• A point on the circumference of the circle $\mathbf (a,b)$

• The clockwise degrees of rotation $\mathbf t$ of the point $(a,b)$ about the center point $(x,y)$

Here's an illustration :

[image: http://i.imgur.com/hQy2HZw.png]

I've tried

$\begin{cases}
x=a+r\;\cos(t) \\
y=b+r\;\sin(t)
\end{cases}$

and it seemed to get me close but it's possible I'm missing an additional piece of the puzzle.

Comment: you have inversed things, this is $a=x+r\cos(t)$ and $b=y-r\sin(t)$.

Comment: You drew your $t$ angle to be >90° which throws off the signs for the trig functions.

Answer (score 1):

Consider that you know how to write $(a,b)$ using $x,y,\mathbf{r},\mathbf{t}$:
$$\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
a=x+\mathbf{r}\cos(2\pi-\mathbf{t}) \\
b=y+\mathbf{r}\sin(2\pi-\mathbf{t})
\end{array}
\right.$$

Answer (score 1):

Draw it with small angles to get

[image: fig1]

$$\left.\begin{aligned}a & =x+r\sin t\\
b & =y+r\cos t
\end{aligned}
\right\} \;\left.\begin{aligned}x & =a-r\sin t\\
y & =b-r\cos t
\end{aligned}
\right\} $$

Comment: Finally someone read the complete question and answered it as written.

Answer (score 0):

Was a bit confused with the above answer, so here's how I got x and y:

(assuming: x and y axis increase in the north east direction)

1. draw a perpendicular line from (a;b) upwards (see attached drawing)
2. Simply solve the following

- x = a - cos(t-90) * r
- y = b + sin(t-90) * r

Edited drawing
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acHPb.png)